# Quickblox: Sign in using custom objects(Android)

Tags: android, quickblox

I want to store more information about my user, hence quickblox user module will not be sufficient for me.
So I am using custom object to store all user information. 
Can anyone please suggest (If possible with code) how do i sign in using custom object data structure i.e. How to check for correct username n password match from all records available..If match found then allow user to sign in else not... 
I think it maybe using getFields() of Class QBCustomObject... but how to use that method???

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot refuse using QBUser. Both password and login will be stored in it. Each custom object has User Id field, so you can use it to connect user and custom object with data. Every time you create an object this field filled in with ID of a user who create this object. That is why you can create a table in custom objects and add all required fields.